# Remove all lines startng with < for all files in current folder

Tags: python-3.x

This is what I have so far. But it just hangs.

```
import os
import sys
import re

directory_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
     for file in files:
            s = ''.join(sys.stdin.readlines())
            s = re.sub(r'(?m)^\<.*\n?', '', s)
```

---

take 2, this still doesnt work but maybe a bit closer?

```
import fileinput
import glob
import sys
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
search = "<"
replace = " "

for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob(path), inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace(search, replace))
```

Comment: easier with sed, though not what you're asking: `sed -i '/^</d' *`

Comment: `sys.stdin` reads from standard input, I believe you're trying to read the files? you want `open`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python inbuilt functions `readlines`, `filter` & `writelines` to achieve your requirement.

I believe the below code serves your purpose.

```
import os

source_dir = 'C:/Users/rlal1/Desktop/test_folder'
files = os.listdir(source_dir)

for each_file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(source_dir, each_file), 'r+') as fp:
        all_lines = fp.readlines()
        filtered = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('<'), all_lines)
        fp.seek(0)
        fp.truncate(0)
        fp.writelines(filtered)
```

Comment: this works for python but not python3, how would you modify it for python3? thanks

Comment: @MattBell It is written in Python 3. What problem are you facing in running above code segment in your python3 environment?